# Forecast future appointments using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping any of you could help me with the following SQL problem, I'm looking for a way to predict future appointments in SQL.

For example, I have an projectnumber "P01155220" (see example table below) where there have been some appointments (see column appointment_date). I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- The next (virtual) appointment would be the last appointment_date + 42 days. For example, the next appointment_date would be 2019-06-27 + 42 days = 2019-08-08.
- This +42 day prediction should continue adding 'rows' as long as the running_total < 450 days.

What is the best way to 'predict' the next upcomming appointment dates?

```
unique_id   appointment_date    days_between    Running_total
P01155220   2018-11-19          0               0
P01155220   2019-01-17          59              59
P01155220   2019-03-21          63              122
P01155220   2019-06-27          98              220
```

Simple query;

```
SELECT
    unique_id
    ,appointment_date
    ,days_between
    ,SUM(days_between) OVER(ORDER BY unique_id,appointment_date) AS Running_total
  FROM [records]
```

The output of the table I would expect should look like this:

```
    |Unique_id|Appointment_date|Days_between|Running_total|
|P0115220|2018-11-19|0|0|
|P0115220|2019-01-17|59|59|
|P0115220|2019-03-21|63|122|
|P0115220|2019-06-27|98|229|
|P0115220|2019-06-27+42|42|271|
|P0115220|2019-06-27+42+42|42|313|
|P0115220|2019-06-27+42+42+42|42|355|
|P0115220|2019-06-27+42+42+42+42|42|397|
|P0115220|2019-06-27+42+42+42+42+42|42|439|
```

Comment: MS SQL server 2016

Comment: You can do that with a `While` loop, but this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - what are you **really** trying to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to get the next appointments until 450 days passed since the beginning.

Comment: In your example, is "the beginning" November 19th or is it June 27th?  Also, what have you tried so far, and with what results?

Comment: Updated the post with expected outcome. Tried to use an u ion all to add the rows using an cross-apply but don't seem to get the output data in the rows like in my expected example.

Comment: Update your post to show what you **actually tried** and the results you **actually got** - don't just give a vague description of what you tried in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to solve it, here's how I did it. I'm not saying this is the best way, but it matches your output. If you don't need the running totals, the second query is much simpler.

```
CREATE TABLE #data(Date date)
INSERT INTO #data VALUES('11/19/2018')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES('1/17/2019')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES('3/21/2019')
INSERT INTO #data VALUES('6/27/2019')

;
WITH
dates
AS (SELECT Date, Elapsed = DATEDIFF(dd, ISNULL(LAG(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date), Date), Date) FROM #data),
run
AS  (SELECT Date, RunningTotal = SUM(Elapsed) OVER (ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) FROM dates  )
SELECT * FROM run
UNION ALL
SELECT  date = DATEADD(dd, 42 * t1.number, l.lastdate),
    RunningTotal = l.RunningTotal + t1.number * 42
FROM    master..spt_values t1
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT lastdate = MAX(Date), RunningTotal = MAX(RunningTotal) FROM run) l
WHERE
    type = 'p'
    AND t1.number > 0
    AND l.RunningTotal + t1.number * 42 < 450

--------
SELECT d.Date
FROM #data d
UNION ALL
SELECT  date = DATEADD(dd, 42 * t1.number, l.lastdate)
FROM    master..spt_values t1
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT firstDate = MIN(date),lastdate = MAX(Date) FROM #data) l
WHERE
    type = 'p'
    AND t1.number > 0
    AND DATEDIFF(dd,l.firstDate,lastdate) + t1.number * 42 < 450
```